# How to use $row results into mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, row, rows

How can I use $row results into a mysqli_query?

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT subcat_ID FROM subcategories WHERE cat_ID=$cat_ID");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
$result2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT subsubcat_name FROM subsubcategories WHERE subcat_ID='".$row['subcat_ID']."'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
        if (isset($row)){
        echo $row['subsubcat_name'];
        echo "<br>";
        }
```

I don't get any error but I can't get it printed.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

==================================================================================

*1st edit*

Because my problem isn't solved yet, I'm explaining it a bit more in depth:

My databases:
- categories: cat_ID, cat_name
- subcategories: subcat_ID, cat_ID, extra_cat_ID, subcat_name
- subsubcategories: subsubcat_ID, subcat_ID, subsubcat_name

At a certain point I get the value of a cat_ID (categories) through an url.
What I want to do is wherever cat_id of categories is the same value as the cat_id or extra_cat_ID like in subcategories (I also want to be able to print subcat_name), where subcat_ID of subcategories is the same as subcat_ID of subsubcategories ---> print subsubcat_name.

```
Categories
-------------------------
cat_ID | cat_name
------------------
4      | Baby & Kids
5      | Bicycles
6      | Boats
7      | Books & Comics
....
13     | Clothes & Accessories
....
35     | Sport & Fitness
36     | Study
....
38     | Toys & Games
....


Subcategories
-------------------------
subcat_ID | cat_ID | extra_cat_ID | subcat_name
------------------------------------------------
....
15        | 4      | 13           | Baby clothes
16        | 4      | 0            | Baby products
17        | 4      | 13           | Kids clothes
18        | 4      | 38           | Toys
19        | 5      | 0            | Bycicles
20        | 5      | 0            | Bycicle gear & Accessories
21        | 6      | 0            | Boat parts
22        | 6      | 0            | Other Boats
23        | 6      | 0            | Power Boats
24        | 6      | 0            | Sailboats
25        | 6      | 35           | Windsurf & Surfing
26        | 7      | 0            | Antiquarian
27        | 7      | 0            | Books
28        | 7      | 38           | Childrens books
29        | 7      | 0            | Comics
30        | 7      | 0            | Magazines & Newspapers
31        | 7      | 36           | Study & Training



Subsubcategories
-------------------------
subsubcat_ID | subcat_ID | subsubcat_name
-----------------------------------------
...
470          | 15        | Baptism outfits
471          | 15        | Bibs
472          | 15        | Body warmers
473          | 15        | Bodysuits
....
496          | 16        | Baby bath
497          | 16        | Baby books
498          | 16        | Baby inserts
499          | 16        | Baby monitors
....
548          | 17        | Belts
549          | 17        | Blouses & Shirts
550          | 17        | Body warmer
551          | 17        | Boots
....
....
740          | 26        | Music
741          | 26        | Navy
742          | 26        | Novel
743          | 26        | Photography
....
....
867          | 30        | Animals
868          | 30        | Arts and Culture
869          | 30        | Branch
870          | 30        | Cars
870          | 30        | Computers
....
....
etc.
```

I hope this clearout things a bit more.

Comment: Your first WHERE statement should be inside the `"`

Comment: Also, you don't need to check if `$row` is set inside a `while ($row...` because if you're inside a `while($row...` then you know it's set. Perhaps you mean `isset($row['subsubcat_name'])`?

Comment: Thanks for replying rybo111.The " was a typo when typing my question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Also even if I use isset($row['subsubcat_name']) It doesn't show anything. No errors, no outprint. Btw, thank you for the tip about checking if $row is set.

Comment: Try setting your SQL query as a variable like this: `$sql = "SELECT...` then echo it. Then run that query in phpMyAdmin. It may show you an error there.

Comment: Problem is still not solved. Maybe my new edit of the question can clear things out. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running two queries you should use a `JOIN`.

For example this `$query` :

```
SELECT subcategories.cat_ID, subsubcategories.subsubcat_name
FROM subcategories
INNER JOIN subsubcategories
ON subcategories.cat_ID=subsubcategories.subcat_ID
WHERE subcategories.cat_ID = ?
```

Preparing your query is more appropriate/safe in this case:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($result = mysqli_prepare($connect, $query)) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "i", $cat_ID);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($result);

    /* fetch data */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        if (isset($row)){
            echo $row['subsubcat_name'];
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
 }
```

[**`DEMO for SQL JOIN`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e3de/2)

---

Got it working. This is the code I used:

```
$result=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT subcategories.cat_ID, subsubcategories.subsubcat_name FROM subcategories INNER JOIN subsubcategories ON subcategories.subcat_ID=subsubcategories.subcat_ID WHERE subcategories.cat_ID = $cat_ID OR subcategories.extra_cat_ID = $cat_ID");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row['subsubcat_name'];
            echo "<br>";
 }
```

Though not sure it is the safe way to do it. Suggestions are always welcome.
Thanks to meda to showing me another approach tho it is not quite the same code.

Comment: Oh nice thanks! Didn't thought of that approach. Gonna test it this evening. Thanks meda!

Comment: @Thoaren you can check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for more info.. I would run two queries only if they are different like a SELECT then an UPDATE for example

Comment: Well, *this* time your *intention* to answer "in the question's general direction" makes perfect sense. It lacks proper syntax though. As usual.

Comment: @YourCommonSense so please help to fix ;)

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in" on this line: "mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "i", $cat_ID);"

Comment: @Thoaren sorry I forgot a semi-colon at the end of `ON subcategories.cat_ID=subsubcategories.subcat_ID;` can you remove it please thanks. here is a demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e3de/2

Comment: @meda I still get the error. I edited the question. Maybe this edit can clear some things out. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use mysqli

object oriented

```
<?php   
    $connect= new mysqli("localhost","user","passwd","database");
    if ($connect->connect_errno){
      echo "could not connect";
    }

    $select = "SELECT * FROM tablename";

    if($result = $connect->query($select)){
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            echo $row->rowname."<br>";
        }
    }
    else { echo 'no result'; }
    $connect->close();  
?>
```

Procedural Style

```
<?php   
    $connect= mysqli_connect("localhost","user","passwd","database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "could not connect";
    }

    $select = "SELECT * FROM tablename";

    if($result = mysqli_query($connect,$select)){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
            echo $row->rowname."<br>";
        }
    }
    else { echo 'no result'; }
    mysqli_close($connect);  
?>
```

Comment: That is Object oriented style. The OP is using Procedural style.

Comment: I never programmed object oriented before. When I implement your example into my code it gives me errors: "Notice: Undefined variable: con in" and "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in".

Comment: you have to set the connection variable first.  like this. $con= new mysqli("localhost","user","passwd","database");

Comment: @Thoaren In your case it be $connect= new mysqli("localhost","user","passwd","database"); I edit the code

Comment: Look at example 2 here:http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: How is this answer relevant to the question?

Comment: questin is "How can I use $row results into a mysqli_query?"

Comment: Thank you. Once I'm at home, I'll try to implement this.

Comment: That's just a TITLE. **Did you happen to read the question body at all?**

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well I was already wondering if this could solve my problem of getting $row results into a mysqli_query WHERE because I don't see it in this answer but I might be wrong me being still in learning process. I'm happy to look at your solution for this if you want.